# Класс для комментариев

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

Тренируюсь разрабатывать простой сайт на asp.net mvc4. Хотел спросить, правильно ли я написал модель для комментариев:

```
public class Coment
{
    [Key]
    public int ComentId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Комментарии")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Novosti")]
    public int NovostiID { get; set; }

    public virtual Novosti Novosti { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Articles")]
    public int ArticlesID { get; set; }

    public virtual Articles Articles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

?

И когда хочу внести комментарий, выдается такая ошибка:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Coments_dbo.Novostis_NovostiID". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-bestgame-20121214163019", table "dbo.Novostis", column 'NovostiID'.
```

Comment: >`Novosti Novosti`

вы издеваетесь?

Comment: за один только транслит надо руки отрубать по локоть)))

Answer (score 1):

Во первых поддержу ответы про транслит. Этого стоит избегать.

Во вторых, Зачем дублировать

```
[ForeignKey("Novosti")]
public int NovostiID { get; set; }
public virtual Novosti Novosti { get; set; }
```

Идентификатор новостей должен содержавться в типе Novosti.
То же самое относится к ArticleID и к UserId.

Comment: Это же внешние ключи(или я что-то не понимаю). Тут тоже так делается: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/asp.net/hh559531

Comment: Проблему решил: в методе действия была ошибка. С классом все в порядке)